# Terraform Azure Data Factory Trigger Schedule - Error When Using Activated With Monthly Frequency

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, azure-data-factory

I created a new Trigger for my Datafactory Pipeline using Terraform's ***azurerm_data_factory_trigger_schedule*** provider key.

The trigger is meant to kick off every 4th of the month, 13:00 UTC.

However, the Status doesn't automatically get set to Started after deployment. Following the changes made on this PR to support activated property,

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/13390

I added ***activated*** to my TF script. Current TF script looks as such:

```
resource "azurerm_data_factory_trigger_schedule" "pipeline_trigger" {
  name                = "Pipeline_MonthlyTrigger"
  data_factory_name   = "dataFactoryName"
  resource_group_name = "resourceGroupName"
  pipeline_name       = "pipelineName"

  frequency           = "Month"
  interval            = 1

  activated           = true

  schedule  {
    days_of_month     = [4]
    hours             = [13]
    minutes           = [0]
  }

}
```

After adding "activated", I end up getting the following error:

> The recurrence schedule of trigger could not have 'WeekDays' for
> recurrence frequency 'Month'." Target="Pipeline_MonthlyTrigger"

I tried different variations like adding "days_of_week" with empty array, or adding an empty "monthly" block inside schedule, but none worked.

Am I doing it wrong or is there really a bug on the latest TF code to support *activated* on *azurerm_data_factory_trigger_schedule*?

What I'm after:

[Datafactory Trigger Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GnPK.png)

Comment: Hello @mysterygrocer, it seems to be some product issue. when activated is true , schedule doesn't work , if we remove schedule block it works fine . Can you please create a github issue on terraform-provider-azure- repo to get it addressed? you can go to this link : https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues

Comment: Thanks @AnsumanBal-MT. That confirms my suspicion that it's a bug. Have raised a ticket on Github as suggested: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/14384

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been confirmed as a `bug` from Terraform side as when we are using `activated = true` , the `schedule block` doesn't seem to be working and errors out .

When ***activated*** is not provided as parameter and schedule is used, then instead of being by ***default true it sets to false***.

**Details for the Bug Fix and Bug can be found on this** **[Github Issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/14384)** and  **[Pull request](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/14391)**